# Visual studio not make me able to define style atrribute on aspx page which is made with aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have made a aspx page with .aspx.vb codebase and it's not make me able to do define style attribute by typing. I am not able to type anything in style attribute.

is this bug in Vs12 ( I got it also in VWD)

```
  <asp:Label runat="server" id="Label26" Text="Positions" style="width:200px;"></asp:Label>
```

I can't edit this when I have style=""; If I restart then I can edit and after sometime it's same problem again.

---

I means I can't type anything in style attribute, it's look like block. When I closed my visual studio and open again I can type but after sometime It's same issue.

I don't thing it's my problem. I have test same thing in my VWD and VS 12 PRO on Win8 PRO.

If I can run this code and it's worked then why I can't do that. if this is not recommanded then why it's work after a IDE restart.

@option. Please read it again, I have this problem with my both VWD12 and VS12 PRO.

Can someone help me to get it worked for me. It's look like a bug in Visual studio. Someone can check this on their IDE with .aspx and aspx.vb file.

Somebody know for now how to get it done for me.

Comment: Sounds to me like there's a problem with your IDE. Not sure if I understand the question correctly.. are you saying that Intellisense isn't working? Or that you can't actually physically change the style of the label in-code?

Comment: @optionsix see the question again

Answer (score 0):

`style` is not an attribute of the `ASP.net`'s `Label` control. It works just for compatibility, but I don't suggest you to use it this way. It's better to use `CssClass` and define all in Css.

Anyway, if you want to add a style from codebehind:

```
Label26.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 200px;")
```

Comment: Thanks for very soon answer. btw I just want to modify the style attribute of my rendered label.

Comment: so If I want to put width:200 then do you means wrap them in span and div and give them style.

Comment: Do you mean you can't *write* in your .aspx file? It's too weird. Did you try reinstalling VS?

Comment: no, I have installed VWD 08 for now and it's work fine. I don't thing it's installation problem. I have reported  it to connect.

Comment: I am going to use 2008 Version of VWD to make it work for me.